# Create shortcut with Delphi and specify its privilege level

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I am using the following code to make shortcuts in Delphi. I want to make a shortcut with "Run this program as an administrator" box checked in Privilege Level properties of shortcut. Is there any way to do this?

```
function MakeShortcut(Dst, Src: String; Desc: String = ''; Arg: String = ''; WorkDir: String = ''; Icon: String = ''; IconI: Integer = 0; Show: Integer = SW_SHOWNORMAL; HotKey: Word = 0): Boolean;
var
  u: IUnknown;
  s: IShellLink;
  f: IPersistFile;
  p: WideString;
begin
try
  u := CreateComObject(CLSID_SHELLLINK);
  s := u as IShellLink;
  f := u as IPersistFile;
  s.SetPath(PChar(Src));
  if (WorkDir = '') then WorkDir := ExtractFileDir(Src);
  s.SetWorkingDirectory(PChar(WorkDir));
  if (Icon = '') then Icon := Src;
  s.SetIconLocation(PChar(Icon), IconI);
  s.SetDescription(PChar(Desc));
  s.SetArguments(PChar(Arg));
  s.SetShowCmd(Show);
  s.SetHotkey(HotKey);
  p := Dst;
  Result := Succeeded(f.Save(PWChar(p), False));
except
  Result := False;
end;
end;
```

Comment: Note that the "run as admin" flag is NOT a property of the shortcut, it's a compatability flag on the exe itself (or rather its current path). The application shoudl really flag this in its manifest.

Comment: @Deanna No, I don't want the application always runs as admin, I want to run it as admin when a special command line argument passes to it. Like: "myapp.exe /install"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`IShellLinkDataList::SetFlags()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774920.aspx) passing [`SLDF_RUNAS_USER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762540.aspx).

I don't have any code samples at hand. But the basic approach will be like this:

```
sldl := s as IShellLinkDataList;
flags := sldl.GetFlags();
sldl.SetFlags(flags or SLDF_RUNAS_USER);
```